# Want to recursively list full path of all files in a directory structure and pipe into text file without wordwrap

Tags: powershell-2.0

I want to get a listing of the full path of every file in a multi-level directory structure, and put that information into a text file - BUT, I don't want long path's to be word-wrapped - I want to have the full path of each line on a single line in the text regardless of how long that line is.

I started out with this command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.FullName.ToString() }
```

I then have tried various means to try and redirect this output to a text file.  First I tried this (but it didn't work):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.FullName.ToString() } | Out-File C:\temp\out.txt
```

Next, I tried just piping all of the StdErr, StdOut etc to the text file thus:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.FullName.ToString() } *> C:\temp\out.txt
```

This last command got close - but still the longer path's are wrapped onto the next line.  I have been trying all sorts of things to try and stop this (wordwrap) from happening.  Can anyone tell me how to get the output from the above command to go into a text file with no word-wraps (even) for very long path's?

thanks heaps,

David. :-)

Comment: `gci -r | select -expand FullName | Out-File foo.txt` however `cmd /c dir/s/b ">foo.txt"` is *a lot* faster. I believe there should be many answers on this topic.

Comment: Thanks - that command got what I was looking for.  :-)